# python 3. Ffinding the center of a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I'm sorry to be posting this with no code, but right now i'm having a hard time understanding arrays and 2D arrays.  My question is, I'm given a 2D array, and a box.  the box must go inside the 2D array in the middle.  the array can be any size, and the box can be any size.  example:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
```

the and the box lets say is 3 meters squared.  so it would end up looking like this

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   
1   2   3   B   B   B   7   8   9   
1   2   3   B   B   B   7   8   9   
1   2   3   B   B   B   7   8   9  
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
```

and it would print out something like [4,4].  From what I've searched online, numpy.shape(array) would give me something like (8,8) correct?  would I to cut that in half and get (4,4) and go from there, or would i have to find a different way?  If the first way is possible, how would i do something like (9,9)?  It would give me (4.5,4.5).  sorry to be asking probably such rudimentary questions, It just that im having a hell of a time even starting this.

we are importing numpy, and are suggested to use numpy.sum()

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum, tutorial or code writing service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.

Comment: If your array is X by X units and your box is Y by Y units there is an excess of `X - Y` in both dimensions. If you want to equalize the excess around the box then there will be `(X - Y)/2` units on all sides. If you end up with some odd numbers and cannot position at fractional units then you have to decide where to put the odd unit and just be consistent.

Comment: The *array* in your example has a shape of (9,9) with indices ranging from 0-8 in both dimensions.